# Apache server ubuntu 10.10 returns a PHTML file to download instead of php file

Tags: apache, configuration, ubuntu, web-config

I seting up LAMP on my ubuntu box. I have only changed the `sites-available-default/default`

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/user/Dropbox/www/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/user/Dropbox/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I connect to my localhost I get a file in return. A `PHTML` with the `index.php` code.

When I connect to connect to `http://192.168.1.133` I get a Forbidden error..

I assume it has something to do with permission and security, but not how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it was because of a missing php module for apache.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep apache
ii  apache2                               2.2.17-1ubuntu1                            Apache HTTP Server metapackage
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                   2.2.17-1ubuntu1                            Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
ii  apache2-suexec                        2.2.17-1ubuntu1                            Standard suexec program for Apache 2 mod_suexec
ii  apache2-threaded-dev                  2.2.17-1ubuntu1                            Apache development headers - threaded MPM
ii  apache2-utils                         2.2.17-1ubuntu1                            utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                         2.2.17-1ubuntu1                            Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                      2.2.17-1ubuntu1                            Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache2-mod-auth-mysql             4.3.9-13ubuntu1                            Apache 2 module for MySQL authentication
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                   5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2                           server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
```

I think (not sure) that `libapache2-mod-php5` is the essential package to run php files with apache. So, make sure at least you have this one installed, and search a little about which packages to install to have a full php/apache installation. If you are installing xampp, download the most recent version and make sure you install it as root.

Answer (score 1):

After installing all the updates to the server in linux ubuntu
apache server seemed to not work
tried to access the website hosted on the server and the result was a phtml file type.
Then look at other pages that install packages sugieron
libapache2-mod-php5
php5 (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17)

The install using LVM Synaptic Package Manager.
Then I wrote the URL of my site. this is working.

Comment: Thanks for joining us Jose.  This does seem to be an answer to the question, but it repeats the same info given in much earlier answers and doesn't offer anything new.